# Operand should contain 1 column(s) when selecting data from another table AS value

Tags: mysql, sql

Can some one please help me here, ive Googled, and looked at other examples with this error but it just confuses me and i cant seem to get my head around this.

im struggling with selecting data AS something else in a  mysql query im getting the following error...

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

What is an simplified term for an Operand?

below is the mysql query...

```
SELECT atable_garage.id, 
       atable_garage.total_votes as num_votes,
       atable_garage.name, 
       atable_garage.address, 
       atable_garage.city, 
       atable_garage.postcode, 
       atable_garage.main_dealer, 
       atable_garage.phone, 
       atable_garage.website, 
       atable_garage.description, 
       atable_garage.years_in_business,
       atable_garage.garage_image,  
       (SELECT(avg(quality_of_repair) + avg(attitude_of_staff) + avg(overall_satisfaction))/3 as rating, 
               count(*) as num_votes 
          FROM atable_feedback 
         WHERE validated = 'Y'
           AND atable_garage.id = garage_id) 
  FROM `atable_garage`
 WHERE valeting = 'Y' 
   AND active = 'Y' 
ORDER BY rating DESC, atable_garage.total_votes DESC
```

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong here? and if possible explain I'm finding it difficult to get my head around this one thanks in advance.

Comment: A sub-select can't return more than one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlated subquery can only return one column at a time. Since you want to have two column, you can restrusture the query by converting it into `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  atable_garage.id, 
        atable_garage.total_votes as num_votes,
        atable_garage.name, 
        atable_garage.address, 
        atable_garage.city, 
        atable_garage.postcode, 
        atable_garage.main_dealer, 
        atable_garage.phone, 
        atable_garage.website, 
        atable_garage.description, 
        atable_garage.years_in_business,
        atable_garage.garage_image,  
        COALESCE(b.rating, 0) rating,
        COALESCE(b.num_votes, 0) num_votes
FROM    atable_garage
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  garage_id,
                    (avg(quality_of_repair) + avg(attitude_of_staff) + avg(overall_satisfaction)) / 3.0 as rating, 
                    count(*) as num_votes 
            FROM    atable_feedback 
            WHERE   validated = 'Y'
            GROUP   BY  garage_id
        ) b ON  atable_garage.id = b.garage_id
WHERE   valeting = 'Y' AND active = 'Y' 
ORDER   BY rating DESC, 
        atable_garage.total_votes DESC
```

Comment: Oh ok of course i didnt think of trying left join. Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

When using a sub-select for a column, you can only return one value, like this:

```
   (SELECT avg(quality_of_repair) + avg(attitude_of_staff) + avg(overall_satisfaction) 
      FROM atable_feedback 
     WHERE validated = 'Y'
       AND garage_id = atable_garage.id
   )/3 as rating,
```